# Where is child_process.js?

Tags: node.js, forever

I am trying to debug a problem with forever/nodejs, and I get this stacktrace in the error log:

```
chdir(): Permission denied

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn EACCES
  at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

This looks to me like  I should be able to look at line 980 of a file named "child_process.js" to see where the error is thrown.  However, I cannot locate such a file on the system even with "find".  Am I missing it somehow, or is the stracktrace lying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the node.js source.  See https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js.  I believe you can also step directly through core node code using node's built-in [debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), or a package such as [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-inspector).

Comment: Are you saying that child_process.js is one of the source files for the node binary, and was somehow compiled into it?

Comment: Okay, it seems surprising to me, but a grep on snippets of child_process.js find matches in bin/node, so it seems those JS files are embedded (not compiled) into node.  If anyone cares to comment on how that is done, I would interested.

Comment: I don't how it's getting bundled up, but node-inspector makes it really easy to open up the node source files by name.  see http://i.imgur.com/U2JJtBO.png