# Obtaining html source code w/ XMLHttpRequest.js for parse.com CloudCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, parse-platform

For Cloud Code (parse.com), I'm trying to scrape web data from another website, but I have been unable to get the source code of the websites as a string.

I tried using the [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmlhttprequest) module

```
    var url = "www.targetWebsite.com";
    
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("cloud/XMLHttpRequest.js").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var doc = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

However, when I try running the code, I get the error `Module child_process.js not found`

which I'm assuming refers to this line in the XMLHttpRequest.js file

```
  var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
```

However, I could not find a `child_process.js` in the downloaded folder to add to the directory.

Is there a way to include this file, or is there a better way to obtain source code?

**EDIT: Using httpRequest cloud function**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("pushFavorites", function(request, response) {

    var xpath = require("cloud/xpath.js"), dom = require("cloud/dom-parser.js").DOMParser;          
    var doc;

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
     
       url: "website.com",
       success: function(httpResponse) {
           doc = new dom().parseFromString(httpResponse.text);
        },
      error: function(httpResponse) {
          console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
   }
});

    var cells = xpath.select("//td[starts-with(@class, 'menugridcell')]", doc);

//etc...
```

On the line declaring the `cells` variable, I'm getting the error: `Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined`

Using console.log,  `httpResponse.text` correctly displayed the source code as a string.  I'm not sure if the error is with the httpResponse or my xpath.  I was able to get the xpath.select() function to work properly for some other manually contrived xml strings.

Comment: the close vote is probably because this question is really asking for a library/resource to solve the problem.  A better form is to pick a solution and get programming help here as you try to use it.

Comment: You might want to add a node.js tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse Cloud Code isn't running node so while you can get some modules to work, not all will. In this case, I doubt you'll be able to as child_process is a core node module (see [Where is child_process.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973116/where-is-child-process-js)) so isn't available in Cloud Code.

Try using [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking) instead which should be able to fulfill your needs.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now, I added more info to the question

Comment: Can't speak to using dom-parser or xpath on Parse but you at least have an async issue. httpRequest is non-blocking so the `xpath.select()` call is occurring before doc has be initialized in the success callback. Try moving all that code into the callback and see if that gets you closer.